# Upload to SFTP server with SSH.NET fails with SftpPathNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the path specified.'

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I'm trying to upload a file over SFTP, using Renci SSH.NET.

**Connecting:**

- Connecting to the sFTP-site, **using SSH.NET**, seems to work: `SftpClient`'s `IsConnected` returns true.
- Connecting **using FileZilla**, however, triggers this warning:

  > Server's Host Key is Unknown

**Uploading:**

1) Using `SftpClient`'s `UploadFile`  method:

```
    client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/Path/" + fileName, null);
```

...I get a `Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException`: 'The system cannot find the path specified.'

- I've tried hardcoding the path - same result.
- I've tried using the `SftpClient`'s `WorkingDirectory` - but that translates into a string of Chinese-looking characters, and doesn't work either.

2) Using `SftpClient`'s `BeginUploadFile` method:

```
    client.BeginUploadFile(fileStream, "/Path/" + fileName, asyncCallback, null, UpdateUploadProgress);
```

...I get no errors/exceptions, but:

- the file isn't uploaded
- `aSyncCallback` and `uploadCallback` don't seem to work

3) using FileZilla, I can upload just fine (using the exact same destination path as above: "/Path/Filename.txt")

---

My code:

```
    var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(IpAddress,
                        Port,
                        UserName,
                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(UserName, Password),
                        new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("rsa.key"));
            connectionInfo.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
            {
                client.Connect();

                if (client.IsConnected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SSH-client is connected");
                }
                var fileStream = new FileStream(FileMaker.GetFullyQualifiedPath(), FileMode.Open);
                client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                string fileName = new FileMaker().GetFileName();
                //client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/Path/" + fileName, null);
                AsyncCallback asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(NotifyUploadComplete);
                client.BeginUploadFile(fileStream, "/Path/" + fileName, asyncCallback, null, UpdateUploadProgress);
                client.Disconnect();
            }
```

Callback handlers:

```
    private void UpdateUploadProgress(ulong uploaded)
    {
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = (MainViewModel)System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("mainViewModel");
        mainViewModel.UploadProgress = uploaded;
    }

    private void NotifyUploadComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File uploaded.", "File uploaded");
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**:
I made a minimal example and tested it (same result).

Using UploadFile:

```
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(IpAddress,
            Port,
            UserName,
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(UserName, Password),
            new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("rsa.key"));
connectionInfo.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();

    if (client.IsConnected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SSH-client is connected");
    }
    var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\File.txt", FileMode.Open);
    client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
    client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/SSHUsersPath/File.txt", null);
    //AsyncCallback asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(NotifyUploadComplete);
    //client.BeginUploadFile(fileStream, "/SSHUsersPath/File.txt", asyncCallback, null, UpdateUploadProgress);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

And here's an excerpt from the requested FileZilla log file:

> 2017-09-21 10:08:36 11252 1 Status: Connected to
>   sshserv.CENSORED.com 2017-09-21 10:08:36 11252 1 Status:
>   Retrieving directory listing... 2017-09-21 10:08:36 11252 1 Command:
>   pwd 2017-09-21 10:08:36 11252 1 Response: Current directory is:
>   "/SSHUsersPath" 2017-09-21 10:08:36 11252 1 Command: ls 2017-09-21
>   10:08:37 11252 1 Status: Listing directory /SSHUsersPath 2017-09-21
>   10:08:37 11252 1 Status: Directory listing of "/SSHUsersPath"
>   successful 2017-09-21 10:08:58 11252 3 Status: Connecting to
>   sshserv.CENSORED.com... 2017-09-21 10:08:58 11252 3 Response:
>   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8 2017-09-21 10:08:58 11252 3
>   Command: open "CENSORED@sshserv.CENSORED.com" 22 2017-09-21
>   10:08:59 11252 3 Command: Trust new Hostkey: Once 2017-09-21 10:09:00
>   11252 3 Command: Pass: ***** 2017-09-21 10:09:00 11252 3 Status:
>   Connected to sshserv.CENSORED.com 2017-09-21 10:09:00 11252 3
>   Status: Starting upload of C:\File.txt 2017-09-21 10:09:00 11252 3
>   Command: cd "/SSHUsersPath" 2017-09-21 10:09:01 11252 3 Response: New
>   directory is: "/SSHUsersPath" 2017-09-21 10:09:01 11252 3 Command: put
>   "C:\File.txt" "File.txt" 2017-09-21 10:09:01 11252 3 Command:
>   local:C:\File.txt => remote:/SSHUsersPath/File.txt 2017-09-21 10:09:01
>   11252 3 Status: File transfer successful, transferred 4 bytes in 1
>   second 2017-09-21 10:09:01 11252 3 Status: Retrieving directory
>   listing of "/SSHUsersPath"... 2017-09-21 10:09:01 11252 3 Command: ls
>   2017-09-21 10:09:01 11252 3 Status: Listing directory /SSHUsersPath
>   2017-09-21 10:09:02 11252 3 Status: Directory listing of
>   "/SSHUsersPath" successful 2017-09-21 10:09:17 11252 1 Status:
>   Deleting "/SSHUsersPath/File.txt" 2017-09-21 10:09:17 11252 1 Command:
>   rm "/SSHUsersPath/File.txt" 2017-09-21 10:09:18 11252 1 Response: rm
>   /SSHUsersPath/File.txt: OK

Comment: Show us FileZilla log file proving that you can upload to `/Path/fileName`

Comment: Show us [mcve] for `client.UploadFile` - that means (among other): real filenames, no stuff like `FileMaker`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Martin, I updated my question.

Comment: OK, but I've asked for example with simple `client.UploadFile`, not `BeginUploadFile`.

Comment: The `client.UploadFile` was included, but commented out. I uncommented it just now (and commented the `client.BeginUploadFile` code).

Comment: OK, I',m quite sure that the problem is `connectionInfo.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;` - Why do you do that? Try to remove that.

Comment: With `connectionInfo.Encoding` = `Encoding.Unicode` commented out, I no longer get an Exception using `UploadFile`. Still, the file isn't uploaded though. (`BeginUploadFile` still doesn't trigger any Exceptions, but doesn't succeed in uploading either). The reason I specified the encodong is to insure special characters are preserved. Perhaps setting the file's encoding to Unicode suffices to that end, I'm not sure.

Comment: Do not use `BeginUploadFile` at this phase. What about `UploadFile`?

Comment: Neither `UploadFile` nor `BeginUploadFile` seemed to work. After a reboot however, `BeginUploadFile` DOES work. Not sure if it works intermittently, I will test that now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `UploadFile` seems to work consistently now. `BeginUploadFile` doesn't (it only worked once, out of several runs of the same code, despite my receiving AsyncCallback). If you post your solution, I'll gladly accept it as an Answer. Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem is this:

```
connectionInfo.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
```

The `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16. No SFTP server will ever handle UTF-16 encoded file names. SFTP server should use UTF-8. For that reason SSH.NET defaults `Encoding.UTF8`. If with UTF-8 the server corrupts non-ascii characters in filenames (the `.Encoding` is about file names, not file contents), it must be because the SFTP is broken and uses some legacy encoding. But for sure, it's not UTF-16. It rather some `ISO*` encoding or `Windows-*` encoding.

---

The other problem is that, when you use `BeginUploadFile`, you do not wait for it to finish and immediately disconnect.